# "Net Send" command into Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I remember that in preceding versions of Windows server there was a command to send to the client (in this case all with Windows 7 -64 bit-) a message that appears on the screen.

Still exist for Windows 2012 r2? What can I adapt?

Thanks.

Comment: 2 people think this question shows research effort.

Comment: When I try "msg /server:nomepc * prova" from prompt, return the error " * inesistente o disconnesso". Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the *msg* command on Windows Server 2012 R2 to trigger a popup message dialog box on a remote computer.

The syntax is as follows:

```
msg {<UserName> | <SessionName> | <SessionID>| @<FileName> | *} [/server:<ServerName>] [/time:<Seconds>] [/v] [/w] [<Message>]
```

For example, to send "Hello" to all logged on users of a PC "host.contoso.com", enter:

```
msg /server:host.contoso.com * Hello
```

For parameter explanations and examples, refer to the [Msg article on MS TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771903.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: I try:- msg /server:nomepc * Messaggio Test - and it run. I try to another workstation after set hklm\system\currentcotrolset\control\terminal server  -> AllowRemoteRPC =1 and give the error : - * inesistente o disconnesso-. Why this error? Thanks.

Comment: Are all workstations and servers joined under the same domain? Did you log on as an domain admin? Also, check the 3 points raised by "That Brazilian Guy" here: http://superuser.com/questions/583649/send-msg-over-lan-wireless